# escaped character in data for pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a txt file to import in pandas but the data contains characters like `L\E9on`, which translates to `Léon`. How can I import this kind of data in pandas? I have tried using encoding as `utf-8` and `raw_unicode_escape`. It still gives out an error `multiple repeat at position 2`.

Answer (score 0):

To process accented character please try `encoding='iso-8859-1'`.

Comment: can you please paste your code, so that we can see where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting!!!

To re-produce this issue at my end, I have created dummy data with consists of the text specified by you and saved it as a .txt file

I am able to import this txt file content into **pandas** data frame without any issues using **read_csv** method

**df=pd.read_csv('spcl.txt')**